# Sum only those elements that passes the condition using map

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements

I have two arrays:
teamA = [97, 112, 101] 
teamB = [109, 95, 123]

Each element in the array is the score of the specific team in one game. I need to set a condition that will sum only the scores above 100. So for one team the condition is: If the team score is above 100 sum that score with another that is also above 100, and if the sum of that scores is higher than the sum of scores of the other team, that team wins.

I tought that through mapping I can take the scores that are above 100, but I get a new array that has the first element of undefined.

My code example:

```
const dolphinsGames = [97, 112, 101];
const koalasGames = [109, 95, 123];

const dolphinsScoreAbove = dolphinsGames.map((dolphinsGame) => {
if (dolphinsGame >= 100) {
    return dolphinsGame;
}
});
const koalasScoreAbove = koalasGames.map((koalasGame) => {
if (koalasGame >= 100) {
   return koalasGame;
}
});
```

The result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O02xS.png)

Comment: please add expected result for a clear understanding ...

Comment: *"Sum only those elements that passes the condition using map"* `map` is not the right tool for this job. A loop is the right tool for this job: `let count = 0; for (const game of dolphinGames) { if (game >= 100) { ++count; } }` Some people would also use `reduce` but outside functional programming with predefined reducers, I don't suggest it -- too easy to get wrong. (But FWIW: `let count = dolphinGames.reduce((game, count) => { if (game >= 100) { ++count; }; return count; }, 0);`)

Comment: Compare the team's average scores to determine the winner of the competition and print it ot the console. Include a requirement for a minimum score of 100. With this rule, a team only wins if it has a higher score than the other team, and at the same time a score of at least 100 points. I hope it is better now to understand.

Comment: @Vukasin - I'm afraid not.

Comment: I tried the filter method and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array with the same length of the array and takes the result of the callback for every item.

Instead, you could take [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which ilters the array and returns either the item or not, depending on the filter function.

```js
const
    valid = score => score >= 100,
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    dolphinsGames = [97, 112, 101],
    koalasGames = [109, 95, 123],
    dolphinsScore = dolphinsGames.filter(valid).reduce(add, 0),
    koalasScore = koalasGames.filter(valid).reduce(add, 0);

console.log(dolphinsScore, koalasScore);

if (dolphinsScore === koalasScore) console.log('draw');
else if (dolphinsScore > koalasScore) console.log('dolphins won');
else console.log('koalas won');
```

Comment: Well, the question is why the MAP function didn't work as expected.

Comment: MAP method converts each item of an array, while the filter method is used to select certain items of an array.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments is this what you need ? though no map used :(

```js
const dolphinsGames = [97, 112, 101];
const koalasGames = [109, 95, 123];

const average = arr => arr.reduce( ( p, c ) => p + c, 0 ) / arr.length;

const dolphinsAvg = average(dolphinsGames);
const koalasAvg = average(koalasGames);

if(dolphinsAvg > 100 && koalasAvg > 100){
    if(dolphinsAvg === koalasAvg){
    console.log('draw') 
  }
  else if(dolphinsAvg > koalasAvg ){
    console.log('dolphins win')
  }
  else{
   console.log('koalas win')
  }
}
else{
    console.log('Average points is less than 100')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Map always creates an array of same length mapping every single entry. In your case the mapping function implicitly returns undefined in your "else" case.

One way to solve this is to use `flatMap`:

```
dolphinGames.flatMap((dolphinGame) => dolphinGame >= 100 ? dolpinGame : [])
```

EDIT:
As discussed in the comments even though this example is working the better options would be a simple `filter` because we are not actually changing the elements in the mapping function.

Comment: still the non-satisfying index is returned as an empty array. Using a filter is the way for this use case.

Comment: It is not `[1,2,3].flatMap(n => n > 1 ? n : []) // [2,3]`. `flatMap` will flatten the empty array. You can also find this approach on the Mozilla doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#for_adding_and_removing_items_during_a_map but I agree that filter is the better option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are trying for using filter() method. Unlike map(), the filter callback function expects true/false to be returned. Hence, I would modify your program as,

```js
const dolphinsGames = [97, 112, 101];
const koalasGames = [109, 95, 123];

const dolphinsScoreAbove = dolphinsGames.filter((dolphinsGame) => {
  if (dolphinsGame >= 100) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
});

const koalasScoreAbove = koalasGames.filter((koalasGame) => {
  if (koalasGame >= 100) {
     return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(dolphinsScoreAbove);
console.log(koalasScoreAbove);
```